# SD Cards for H4N

Tags: zoom-h4n

I'm looking for SD cards for my H4N and I would to get some feedback from those are more familiar than me on the topic.

Looking on the confirmed list of SD cards by Zoom, I'm still a little unsure of what works well. I can't even find the recommended SanDisk 32GB card. I'm currently using an old SanDisk SDHC Class 2 4GB that isn't even sold anymore.

I understand that Class 10 and UHS-1 cards are faster but are there any problems/limitations? The only limitation listed on the Zoom website is SDHC up to 32GB.

Looking at Sandisk (seems the most recommended for SD cards), would the higher end cards like the Ultra or Extreme series bring faster boot/save times or would it just not work at all?

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to stick to the exact cards in the list.

I have had a series of problems with write errors on my H4n with several different SD cards.
In the beginning I bought a class 10 - 32gb Sandisk and had constant write errors.
Then I used a class 10 - 16gb Sandisk and had the same problems.
After that I tried a smaller 8gb class 10 card from Kingston and stil got write errors.
In the end I decided to pay more attention to the exact model numbers of the recommended SD cards and realised that the 32 Sandisk in the list was a Class 4 and the 8gb Kingstons where classes 2, 4 and 6.
So i managed to find a couple of Transend 8gb class 10 TS8GSDHC that are in the actual list and now everything works fine!

Comment: For what its worth, I've used Sandisk 16GB Class 6 and 32 GB Class 10 on the H4n with zero issues.

Comment: Are the write errors obvious like an error message on the H4N or is it something that you notice in the recording afterwards?

Comment: In all cases i have had a "write error" message after stoping a recording, and the actual file usually had small gaps. After receiving a "write error" the card had to be formated and most of the time i had to eject it and reboot the H4n.

Comment: I'll try to look out for that. I was concerned about this because I saw a comment on the web where someone had this problem with a card on their list. And some of those cards are discontinued/not updated.

Comment: Why wouldn't any *standard* SD/SDHC card with requird speed class work? If anything it pushes the card a lot less than a video recorder.

Comment: Any card should have worked, but there are probably compatibility issues between certain types and brands of SD cards, and the card controller of the recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind, that larger SD cards causes longer boot-up time of H4n. It took 25secs with 16GB SD card class 10.

BTW: the card is working well.